# htacces after ErrorDocument redirect url remains unchange

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am preventing directory listing by htaccess, but after it gets directed to index the url does not changes.

if user visits http://www.searchme.com/images

it will redirect the page to homepage, but the url remains the same http://www.searchme.com/images

so if I click on any link the url becomes http://www.searchme.com/images/about.php instead it should become http://www.searchme.com/about.php

```
 #IndexIgnore /images/*
 Options -Indexes
 ErrorDocument 404 /searchme/index.php
 ErrorDocument 403 /searchme/index.php
```

Comment: Is that all in the .htaccess file?

Comment: yes thats all, i want to redirect to index.php when user visits images folder, but the url does not changes after redirection

Comment: by url i mean address bar url does not changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should mention entire path , in error document

```
     Options -Indexes
     ErrorDocument 404 http://127.0.0.1/musaada/index.php
     ErrorDocument 403 http://127.0.0.1/musaada/index.php
```